# XSLT on XML node specific

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to write XSLT for tree structured XML

My XML is as blow:

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>     <product>
>        <auto>
>           <admin>
>               <date>2015</date>
>               <subject>
>                  <id>1</id>        
>               </subject>
>           </admin>
>           <report>
>              <Fname>John</Fname>
>           </report>
>       </auto>
>       <auto>
>         <admin>
>            <date>02/02/2015</date>
>            <subject>
>               <id>1</id>       
>           </subject>
>        </admin>
>        <report>
>           <Fname>Jack</Fname>
>        </report>
>      </auto>
>   </product>
> ```

Running XSLT is :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
>   <xsl:template match="/">
>      <html lang="en">
>      <head>
>         <title>Example</title>
>         <script type="text/javascript">
>         <![CDATA[
>         function toggleDisplay(element) 
>         {                
>            element.style.display = element.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'; 
>         };
>         function toggleDisplayAll(elements) 
>         { 
>            for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
>               toggleDisplay(elements[i]);
>            }
>         }   
>        ]]>
>        </script>
>      </head>
>      <body>
>        <h1>Example</h1>
>        <xsl:apply-templates/>
>      </body>
>    </html>
>  </xsl:template>
>  <xsl:template match="product/auto">
>    <ul>
>       <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')); return false;" href="#">
>       <xsl:value-of select="report/Fname"/>
>       </a>
>       <xsl:apply-templates select="admin"/>
>     </ul>
>   </xsl:template>
>   <xsl:template match="date">
>      <li style="display:none;">
>         <xsl:value-of select="concat('Date : ',.)"/>
>      </li>
>   </xsl:template>  
>   <xsl:template match="admin">
>      <ul  style="display:none;">
>         <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li')); return false;" href="#">
>         <xsl:text>Admin: </xsl:text>
>        </a>
>        <ul style="display:none;">
>           <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
>        </ul>
>      </ul>
>    </xsl:template>
>    <xsl:template match="id">
>     <li style="display:none;">
>        <xsl:value-of select="concat('ID : ',.)"/>
>     </li>
>    </xsl:template>
>    <xsl:template match="subject">
>        <li style="display:none;">
>            <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li')); return false;" href="#">
>              <xsl:text>Subject: </xsl:text>
>            </a>
>        <ul style="display:none;">
>           <xsl:apply-templates select='*'/>
>        </ul>
>       </li>
>     </xsl:template>
>   </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```

After runing this code data will be displayed as below

> ```
>   John
>   Jack
> ```

on click of John

> ```
>   John
>      Admin
>    Jack
> ```

Now on click of Admin

> ```
>   John
>      Admin
>        Date: 2015
>        Subject: 
>           ID: 1
>   Jack
> ```

Here i want to display "ID" under "Subject" node, on "on click" of its parent that is "subject" node but it is showing it on click of "Admin" node.

how to control this action. How to control to node specific action

I may posted this question repeatedly. Please help me out to resolve this.

here is the html, where i am achiving this functionality using Jquery

> ```
>  $('.expand').click(function() {
>   $('ul', $(this).parent()).eq(0).toggle();
>   });
>
> ul li ul {
>   display: none;
>   }
>
> <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>  <ul>
>   <li>
>     <a class="expand">Root</a>
>      <ul>
>        <li>
>          <a class="expand">Child</a>
>           <ul>
>            <li>
>              <a class="expand">Super Child</a>
>            </li>
>          </ul>
>        </li>
>      </ul>
>   </li>
> </ul>
> ```

Please help me ..how to achive the same i xslt

Comment: When you say "this code data will be displayed", do you mean that's what you want to happen, or that's what is actually happening?

Comment: That is what is actually happening .

Comment: This question would be easier to digest and answer if you separate XSLT issues from HTML/Javascript issues. Can you determine an HTML (with Javascript) page that does what you want? Then the question is "How can I produce this HTML page using XSLT?" and the answerer can ignore issues of clicking. If not, then the question is "What HTML/Javascript do I need in order to have clicking behave the way I want?" in which case the answerer can ignore XSLT issues.

Comment: *"I may posted this question repeatedly.*" **Please don't do that.**

Comment: I am really sorry for this.. What i did here is, posted one more question with more details and clear tags.

Comment: I dont know how to resolve this issue so

Comment: Please find the html sample